# Allowing an end user to input sets of words

Tags: python

I have been working on this hangman game, and it currently runs fine. The game uses a random word from the array of words in the program. I would like the program to allow and end user to input a new set of words, if they want to. However, I have no idea how to do this; any ideas?
Here is the code currently:

```
name=(input("Please enter your player name: "))
print("Hello " + name + " welcome to hangman!")
import random
score=6
HANGMANPICS = ['''
_______
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
LIVES=6
''', '''
_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
      |
      |
      |
LIVES=5
''', '''
_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
  |   |
      |
      |
LIVES=4
''', '''
_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
  |-  |
      |
      |
LIVES=3
''', '''
_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
 -|-  |
      |
      |
LIVES=2
''', '''
_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
 -|-  |
 /    |
      |
LIVES=1
''', '''

_______
  |   |
(°?°) |
 -|-  |
 / \  |
      |
LVIES=0
''']
words = 'albania andorra armenia austria azerbaijan belarus belgium bulgaria croatia cyprus denmark england estonia finland france georgia germany greece hungary iceland ireland italy kosovo latvia liechtenstein lithuania luxembourg macedonia malta moldova monaco montenegro netherlands norway poland portugal romania russia serbia slovakia slovenia spain sweden switzerland turkey ukraine'.split()
def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print('Missed letters:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Returns the letter the player entered. This function makes sure the player entered a single letter, and not something else.
    while True:
        print('Guess a letter.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter.')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please enter a LETTER.')
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


print('H A N G M A N\nEuropean countries edition')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    # Let the player type in a letter.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        # Check if the player has won
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('Yes! The secret word is "' + secretWord + '"! You have won!')
            print ("Your score was " + str(score) + "/6")
            score=6
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
        score=score-1
        # Check if player has guessed too many times and lost
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"')
            gameIsDone = True
            print("Your score was " + str(score) + "/6\nBetter luck next time kid!;)")
            score=6

    # Ask the player if they want to play again (but only if the game is done).
    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: You just have to update words, why don't you do that?

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you mean? how would I do that? @theharshest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic solution that should get you started.

Have the user input a file of words at the command line:

```
python hangman.py file-with-words.txt
```

Where file-with-words.txt contains:

```
British Columbia,Alberta,Saskatchewan,Manitoba,Ontario,Quebec,Newfoundland,New Brunswick,Prince Edward Island,Nova Scotia,Nunavut,Yukon
```

In your script, open and consume the file:

```
words_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
words = words_file.read().split(',')
words_file.close()
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
```

Put in some error handling and strip out any new lines that you may encounter and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your input set of words into a file. You might need a regular expression to make sure only valid words are allowed, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> words = "Example Word List"
>>> words += " " + input("Add word to word list: ")
Add word to word list: Another
>>> print(words)
Example Word List Another
```

However, rather than have a list of words in one long string separated by spaces, I would strongly recommend just using the variable type `list` for your words. In which case it would look like this:

```
>>> words = ["Example","Word","List"]
>>> words.append(input("Add word to word list: "))
Add word to word list: Another
>>> print(words)
['Example', 'Word', 'List', 'Another']
```

But with this solution, your added words are only going to be available while your program is open, and you'll lose them if you close the game. Better would be to save your words in a text file, so that if you add to them, you'll keep the words.